# How to count different values of records in same column for single id in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table like

student table

```
id|classid|name     |sectionid
--|-------|---------|-------
1 |1      |ashok    |1
2 |1      |viji     |2
3 |2      |sreekesh |1
```

class table

```
id|name
--|----
1 |class1     
2 |class2
```

section table

```
id|name
--|----
1 |A     
2 |B
```

homework table

```
id|classid|activity   |sectionid
--|-------|-----------|---------
1 |1      |test       |1
2 |1      |assignment |2
3 |1      |test       |2
4 |1      |test       |2
5 |1      |assignment |2
6 |2      |assignment |1
```

I want to count class1 student's test activity as total test and assignment activity as total homework. 
my expected result is like:

```
student_name|class_name|total_test|total_assignment|section
------------|----------|----------|----------------|--------
ashok       |class1    |3         |2               |A
viji        |class1    |3         |2               |B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this ([check at sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e7de/5)).

```
SELECT s.name AS student_name,
  c.name AS class_name,
  COUNT(IF(h.activity = "test", h.id, NULL)) AS total_test,
  COUNT(IF(h.activity = "assignment", h.id, NULL)) AS total_assignment
FROM student s
  JOIN class c ON s.classid = c.id
  JOIN homework h ON h.classid = c.id
WHERE c.id = 1 AND h.sectionid = 2
GROUP BY s.id, c.id
```

Update for sections.

Homework must be counted only if it has same section as student? You can achieve it this way ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/969ae/1)):

```sql
SELECT s.name AS student_name,
  c.name AS class_name,
  COUNT(IF(h.activity = "test", h.id, NULL)) AS total_test,
  COUNT(IF(h.activity = "assignment", h.id, NULL)) AS total_assignment,
  sec.name AS section
FROM student s
  JOIN class c ON s.classid = c.id
  JOIN homework h ON h.classid = c.id AND h.sectionid = s.sectionid
  JOIN section sec ON sec.id = s.sectionid
GROUP BY s.id, c.id
```

Comment: Yeah...!! its working.. but i want to filter with section also.. for example class1 students viji and ashok belongs to section A and Section B.. each section have different test and assignmet.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry, but there is no info about sections in your question. Which table contains them? I think, if you add sections details in your question, I can modify answer to use them.

Comment: Look at the update, please. Is that what you want? Count only homeworks in the same section as student.

Comment: Thanks andrew.. but How can i display the section name of the student. ?

Comment: I think there is no join for section table in your query.

Comment: Updated. Section name added to query.

Answer (score 0):

I will go with Andrew answer, but the below is another way of getting exact results as you want

```
select s.name as student_name, c.name as class_name,count(hw1.activity) as total_test,(select count(activity) from homework hw2
where hw2.classid=s.classid and hw2.classid=c.id and activity='assignment') as total_assignemnt
from homework hw1 join student s on hw1.classid=s.classid and hw1.activity='test' join class c on hw1.classid=c.id
group by s.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
   SELECT ST.STUDENTNAME, CT.CLASSNAME,
    COUNT(HW1.CLASSID) AS [TOTAL TESTS], COUNT(HW2.CLASSID) AS [TOTAL ASSIGNMENTS]    
     FROM STUDENT AS ST 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN CLASSTABLE CT ON CT.ID= ST.CLASSID
     LEFT OUTER JOIN HOMEWORK HW1 ON HW1.CLASSID = CT.ID AND HW1.ACTIVITY='TEST'
     LEFT OUTER JOIN HOMEWORK HW2 ON HW2.CLASSID = CT.ID AND HW1.ACTIVITY ='ASSIGNMENT'
     GROUP BY ST.STUDENTNAME
```